# Cannot call function in Vuejs when using SDK JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sdk

I try to using JavaScript SDK in Vuejs, I use login facebook button:

```
<template>
  <div>
  <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="false" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
  </div>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
   data() {
     return: { }
   },
   methods: {
    checkLoginState: function() {
      console.log("logged")
     }
   }
  }
</script>
```

However, I cannot see result. How can I fix this error?

Comment: Please show all of your Vue code.  Where is your Vue instance, Vue component etc?

Comment: I just write one component, have a login with facebook button. I only want to try to show something after login success. I login success to facebook, but it cannot show something in console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the Facebook SDK only knows about the function in the `window` scope, your function is in the `local scope`. This is true for so many, many other libraries. The solution is to bind this to the window when you create / mount the component.

```
created() {
    window.checkLoginState = this.checkLoginState
}
```

Now your local component method will be called when the `onlogin` event is returned from the `FB` api.

Alternatively you can use other binding syntaxes, or just build the button yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know window and local scope =))